# High Charts / StockChart: x axis values

Tags: highcharts

I am populating a High Charts Stock chart. This chart shows both the data points on the y-axis as well as a zoom in/out view at bottom. The data points display fine.

My problem is with the x-axis: I cannot get the years in the x-axis or the zoom to correspond with the years in the data points, that is, 1831 - 2014; instead, the zoom feature and the x-axis only go up to the 1990s (as opposed to this year.)

I think the problem lies in how the pointinterval is calculated

```
pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000000 // one day
```

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8HLCF/

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highstock options reference for [pointInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.pointInterval):

**pointInterval**: Number
If **no x values are given** for the points in a series, pointInterval defines the interval of the x values in milliseconds. For example, if a series contains one value each day, set pointInterval to 24 * 3600 * 1000.

You have defined `x` values. There is no need to use `pointInterval`. And additionaly your comment is wrong, you defined 1000 days instead of 1 day.

Default buttons for `rangeSelector` are not much useful for your data. I defined new range selector for 1y, 5y and All.

And it seems that data format is wrong. I change years to returns primitive value of Date object. See [MDN docs for Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf)

Updated [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8HLCF/2/)